# get feed when some one tagged user in photo FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I want feed when some one tagged user in photo currently i am only able to get that photo but not feed with comments and likes as below

```
select object_id,src from photo where pid in (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE  subject=me())
```

FYI currently i need to get first all photos then have to check whether it is photo of user himself or tagged by someone. so it seem lil bit complex..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sorted out finally...Through below FQL you can get with type=65

```
 SELECT type,post_id, actor_id, message,comments,attachment,description,created_time,updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id =me()
```